# Unable to exit Flutter app in Android 12.0

Tags: java, android, flutter

I'm trying to exit the app by pressing the back button on Android. Pre Android 12, my `MainActivity.onDestroy` gets called but with Android 12.0, it's not getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `MainActivity` extends `FlutterActivity` and not `FlutterFragmentActivity` as with Android 12, the later's `onDestroy` won't get called. So:

Works for all Android versions:

```java
class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {}
```

Works for Android < 12.

```java
class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.
On android12 pressing the back button on the root activity does not exit the activity.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#back-press

Answer (score 0):

Note: flutter project must be supported Android x

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Handle the back button event
                Log.i(TAG, "handleOnBackPressed: back pressed");
                finish();
            }
        };
        getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }
}
```

For more details check:-
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

Answer (score -1):

Please refer below code

```
FlatButton(
  child: new Text("Exit"),
  onPressed: () {
    (Platform.isIOS) ? exit(0) : SystemNavigator.pop();
  },
),
```

Comment: Please read the question again.

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].